# disabling sound in a single application in blackberry

Tags: audio, blackberry, text-to-speech

I just did a dictionary application in blackberry along with a speech to text conversion support .Everything is working fine. Now i wanted to disable the sound when the user needs So how can i do it programmatically .Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
use the flag value as reference


if flag value is true then user click on item then it will play the sound
else sound wont play and display one dialog that Do you want enable sound with two options yes or no 
            if user click on yes then make flag value as true and item.setText("Voice Disable"); otherwise no action means no changes in flag
             in your list item click listener write condition as following
            if(flag==true)
            {
                write your logic to play
            }
```

sample code is

```
public class app extends UiApplication{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new app().enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public app() {
        pushScreen(new SampleScreen()); 
    }
}
class SampleScreen extends MainScreen
{
    static boolean flag=true;
    MenuItem item=null;
    public SampleScreen() {

//      use the flag value as reference
//      if flag value is true then user click on item then it will play the sound
//      else sound wont play and display one dialog that Do you want enable sound with two options yes or no 
//      if user click on yes then make flag value as true and item.setText("Voice Disable"); otherwise no action means no changes in flag
//       in your list item click listner write condition as following
//      if(flag==true)
//      {
//          write your logic to play
//      }



        // you already implement 

        item=new MenuItem("Voice Disable",0,100) {
            public void run() {
                if(flag)
                {
                    flag=false;
                    item.setText("Voice Enable");
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Dialog.inform("Voice Disable succesfully");
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    flag=true;
                    item.setText("Voice Disable");
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Dialog.inform("Voice Enable succesfully");
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        };
        addMenuItem(item);

    }
}
```